# Document store on top of existing PostgreSQL

Tags: json, database, postgresql, jsonb

We have a database based on PostgreSQL. An entity is stored in one table with its core attributes. There is a separated table that contains names of attributes and another table for the value of attributes.

To be more specific we have something like this:

```
usersTable: [id, name, surname] - [1, Johny, Doe]
attrNamesTable: [attrId, attrName] - [1, titleBefore]
attrValuesTable: [attrId, attrValue, userId] - [1, prof, 1]
```

I need a framework that will be on top of this database and will allow access to the records as if they were documents, i.e.:

```
user: {
    id: 1,
    name: Johny,
    surname: Doe,
    attributes: {
        titleBefore: prof
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea about such framework? Any suggestion might help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jsonb functions and operators:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select to_jsonb(t) || jsonb_build_object('attributes', json_object_agg("attrName", "attrValue")) as "user"
from "usersTable" t
join "attrValuesTable" a on a."userId" = t."id"
join "attrNamesTable" n using ("attrId")
group by t.id
```

Test it on [DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3f87731b2e966fc6319478fc4c532900)

Comment: Thank you a LOT! I will definitely give it a try, it looks great!